# C# datagridview does not contain rows

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I am working on a program in which i would like to display the contents of a database on the application, the user also has to be able to edit the values so i decided that a datagridview would be the best choice.

I have succesfully made the datagridview(by dragging and dropping it onto the winform), and have succesfully set the datasource(the content is shown).

---

**setting the datasource of the datagridview:**

```
db = new DatabaseHandler();

userDB = db.Get("users");
dtgv_users.DataSource = userDB.DefaultView;
dtgv_users.Update();
```

---

I have also set some eventhandlers for the ending of the edit and the validation event:

```
private void dtgv_users_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    string id = userDB.Rows[e.RowIndex]["id"] + "";
    string column = userDB.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].ColumnName;
    var rows = dtgv_users.Rows;
    string data = dtgv_users.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value + ""
    db.Update("users", String.Format("{0}='{1}' WHERE id={2}", column, data, id));
}

private void dtgv_users_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        dtgv_users.CancelEdit();
}
```

---

But i have encountered a problem: when i edit the first row in the datagridview and press enter i get the following problem: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`, if i manually check what the rows are in the datagridview by debugging, i realise that it does not contain any rows.

---

How can i fix this problem, why does the datagridview not contain any rows?

I hope you guys can help me out!.

Kind Regards,
Giovanni

---

**edit**

the problem lied with the `Initialize` removed this from the code and it works, THANKS!.

Comment: change the following `dtgv_users.Update();` to `dtgv_users.Refresh();` also is there a reason why you have `InitializeComponent();` in your `dtgv_users_CellValidating` eventHandler

Comment: i have donet his just now, and i received the same error

Comment: what does this method return `db.Get("users");` a `DataTable, DataSet, ...` when you use the Debugger, what line does it error on ..

Comment: the method returns a datatable

Comment: `InitializeComponent();` in `dtgv_users_CellValidating` ?!

Comment: you should be able to bind the datatable to the dtgv_users by doing the following dtgv_users.DataSource = userDB;` please tell us when and where the error happens

Comment: exactly like i say in the post, the error comes when i change a value and press enter, on receiving the data, the rows that are inside are gone when i need to fetch the data from it.

Comment: then read your own code and remove the following come on - remove the `InitializeComponent();` call inside this method `dtgv_users_CellValidating` it's not needed ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a breakpoint here: `dtgv_users.DataSource = userDB.DefaultView;` and make sure your `userDB.DefaultView` has values in it.

Also, what is the `DefaultView` - I'm assuming it's a table - but if not just bind to the table directly and then save the changes when your done.

Comment: it has 1 row in it

Comment: also has values, i checked the contents of the datagridview AFTER it was set and after the datasource was set there is a row inside, but apearently it loses the rows when i make an change

Comment: already done this, but its not even getting there.

Comment: Where exactly is the error happening?